# how to set height of cell programmatically depending on content

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, height, heightforrowatindexpath

I have UITableView where I have text OR text + images.

What I want to do the height of cell depending on the text & images.

I have fixed size of image (let's say 300 width x200 height).

Any idea how can I set height of cell based on content.

Lets say if I have text, height should be 200px and if I have text/ images, I will height 400 px.

Any idea how to set height in such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

As for the width, a table view is a view, so it inherits `UIView` properties. So to change the width you can change the value of `bounds.size.width`.

Comment: so for that indexpath, if there is image, I will return 400 else 200... right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use (UITableViewDelegate method)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then you can use (UITableView method)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To get your cell and just check either type, if you have different types for the two cells or some property or size of content and return correct height.